# Is there a way to list the most recent dates for an event based on data in other columns?

Tags: sql

I am working to write a query that shows the most recent job start date for each person with extended families with in the past year (I should not show future dates)  It is possible that multiple families (in multiple states) may have started their job on the same date.  In that case, I need to list the state(s), both people, and the respective dates.  However, I should only list each state/person pair once.

Additionally, if the person didn't start their job within the past year, I should still list the persons name but in the place of the state name, I should have the query return NULL and the date return NULL.

Below is the date in the raw table:

```
LOC FAM PPL MILESTONE_ID    MILESTONE_NAME  START_DATE  
WI  Smith   Mike    1   End College 9/4/2017 0:00  
WI  Smith   Mike    2   Start Job   9/4/2017 0:00  
WI  Smith   Bob 1   End College 6/4/2019  
WI  Smith   Bob 2   Start Job   6/4/2019  
IL  Thomas  Mike    1   End College 1/4/2019  
IL  Thomas  Mike    2   Start Job   6/4/2019  
IL  Thomas  Bob 1   End College 12/4/2019  
IL  Thomas  Bob 2   Start Job   6/4/2019
```

I know that I need to use a subquery to get the most recent job start dates but my subquery isn't behaving as expected.  I have also tried using a CTE but that isn't working either.

This is what I have so far.  I haven't gotten the subquery to work correctly.  I still need to add the NULL portion of the situation above

```
Select family.*     
From 
FAMILY.KEYINFO      as  family     
Inner Join  
(Select family.milestone_id, MAX(family.start_date) as LatestDate  
    from FAMILY.keyinfo  
    group by milestone_id) groupeddate  
    on family.milestone_id=groupeddate.milestone  
    where family.start_date<= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   
    and family.start_date > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
```

Below is what I would expect the answer to be if the query was correct:

```
LOC PPL     START_DATE  
N/A Mike    N/A  
N/A Mike    N/A  
WI  Bob 6/4/2019  
IL  Mike    6/4/2019  
IL  Bob 6/4/2019
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want window functions:

```
select f.*
from (select f.*,
             rank() over (partition by fam order by start_date desc as seqnum
      from families f
      where milestone_name = 'Start Job'
     ) f
where seqnum = 1;
```